# Can We Build Series

Tags: discussion, reference

There is a now series of questions that have been asked to create great Feats of construction from myths in a realistic way, Think [Anatomically Correct](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series/2798#2798) but for buildings.

And below should a summarized list of all of the questions in order of post, so that a link to this meta post should be enough for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Questions in order of appearance are as follows;

1 - [Can we build Noah's Ark](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28018/how-big-is-noahs-ark)
2 - [Can We build an always changing Maze](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41517/how-do-i-build-an-always-changing-maze)
3 - [Can We Build Erebor](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/41667/can-we-build-erebor)
4 - [Can we build a roguelike maze?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/126727/21222)
5 - [Can we build a 3D maneuver gear from Attack on Titan?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/127303/21222)

Comment: How are questions 2 and 4 any different from each other? As I am reading both of them, they are both asking the same thing- how to build a maze that can change and move around. Is #4 asking how the maze can be reset?

Comment: @JohnLocke I agree, but the court of public opinion has decided that question 4 on this list is not a duplicate. I have voted to close the question due to its nature however.

Comment: Upvoted your comment on that question, maybe another moderator will see it and decide it is a duplicate. The 17 comments on the question don't exactly help people to see it.